# FTP file successfully transferred but is not true

Tags: java, ftp

Here is my simple code:

```
public boolean sendCSV() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Translating from xls to csv...");
    File xls = new File("file.xls");
    File csvFile;
    csvFile = CSVManager.xlsToCsv(xls);
    csvFile.renameTo(new File("file.csv"));

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("Establishing connection...");
        client.connect(ftpHost, ftpPort);
        System.out.print(client.getReplyString());
        System.out.println("Connection ok.");
        if (client.login(ftpUser, ftpPass)) {
            System.out.println("Login ok");
            System.out.print(client.getReplyString());
            System.out.println("Setting PASV");
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            System.out.print(client.getReplyString());

            if (client.changeWorkingDirectory("/MYDIR")) {
                System.out.println("Dir changed");
                System.out.print(client.getReplyString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error changing dir");
                System.out.print(client.getReplyString());
            }
            String filename = csvFile.getName();
            TrayIconManager.SwitchTrayToFull();
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            if (client.storeFile(filename, fis)) {
                System.out.println("File sent");
                System.out.print(client.getReplyString());

            } else {
                System.out.println("Error during sending file");
                System.out.print(client.getReplyString());

            }
        }

        if (client.logout()) {
            System.out.println("Logout ok");
            System.out.print(client.getReplyString());
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Logout problem");
            System.out.print(client.getReplyString());
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem? The output says that

> File sent
>   226-29 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 512000 Kb
>   226-File successfully transferred
>   226 0.343 seconds (measured here), 30.59 Kbytes per second

but is not true, because once I check on the ftp server the file is not there!
Why Kbytes used is 0%? Maybe is that the error?
The code seems to be ok, also the output.
So what is the real problem?

Comment: Can you upload a file using a regular FTP client? If you can, show us a log file. What `FTPClient` are you using? Apache Commons? Again, show us a log.

Comment: The message "29 Kbytes used" seems to come from the FTP server. It's some custom report of your specific FTP server. Not sure what that means. But I would guess it shows a disk usage (0% of your disk quota is used). So it does not indicate any problem.